# "decision being made" What piece of grammar is it?

Tags: gerunds, gerund-clauses

Here is a few examples of sentences with "decision being made":

1. [www.bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/higher/business_management/business_enterprise/decision_making_business/revision/3/): *PESTEC factors could have an impact on the decision being made, for example ...*
2. [www.co-intelligence.org](http://www.co-intelligence.org/I-decisionmakingwithout.html): *When I first saw a decision being made without any decision-making I was trapped ...*

What piece of grammar is used here?

Comment: "Decision being made" is a noun phrase with "decision" as head and the gerund-participial clause "being made" as modifier. Some people wrongly call such clause 'reduces relatives, but I'd strongly advise you to avoid that term - it's a misnomer and just nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are examples of the **passive voice**, the **present continuous** tense, and a **reduced relative clause**.

The passive voice is created by using *to be* and the past participle of the verb.  The verb in this case is *to make*, so the past participle is "made".

It's the present continuous tense because the form of *to be* is "is being".

It's a reduced relative clause because you could rewrite them with a relative pronoun and a *be* verb, like

> PESTEC factors could have an impact on the decision being made

as

> PESTEC factors could have an impact on the decision **that is** being made

But you can leave out the pronoun and *be* verb (like "that is") because the verb in the relative clause is progressive ("being"); that's what makes it a reduced relative clause.

References:

- [Reduced Relative Clauses](http://www.eslgold.com/grammar/reduced_relative_clauses.html)
- [Continuous Forms of the Passive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv119.shtml)

Comment: They are only semantically continuous, not syntactically. The "being" in "being made" is the passive auxiliary, not the continuous one.